# Improve appearance of part attributes

Tags: usability, gui-design, windows-os

I develop a Windows application that manages parts.

1. On the left I have a tree that groups the different types of parts
2. On the right top all parts of the selected tree-type are listed.
3. And when clicking on a part in top list, below the part with its attributes is shown.

Now what bothers me is the arrangement of the part attributes under point 3.
Is there a better way to do it?

Currently I build 2 or 3 rows of attributes depending on the number of attributes to show.

The current layout has some disadvantages

- It looks unordered and hurts the eyes
- If a user does not use the app in full-screen then attributes on row 3 might not be visible and neither attributes at the bottom.
- There is a lot of blank space

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to fit everything in to the single view. You could use a dialog window for editing each of the top table rows. The dialog could then have tabbed navigation for each of the sections within your form. This will allow you more space for the controls themselves and be beneficial if you need to add more in future. See examples below:

[image]
[image]